# How to split a UITextField into two UITextField

Tags: swift2

I have one UITExtField i.e Price, I want to split that UITextField into two UITextField to put the range of price. For example. when the user click on the Price TextField it will split into two UITextField and the user have to put the range like 10,000 to 20,000. How can i achieve this in swift. I didnt find any useful solution on google. Any help please. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: I am almost certain that is impossible, you might want to consider using 2 UItextFields

Answer (score 0):

As 4oby commented, you will need to use two `UITextField`s.

Use the methods available in `UITextFieldDelegate` to listen for editing events, and show or hide the second text field when necessary.